# Simulating Click - ƒ click() { [native code] }

Tags: javascript

I am using pure javascript to simulate a click on a website. The website I am accessing is:

> https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/tv-and-home-entertainment/televisions/televisions/samsung-qe75q75tatxxu-75-smart-4k-ultra-hd-hdr-qled-tv-with-bixby-alexa-google-assistant-10206434-pdt.html

and I am trying to click the add to basket button, but it wont work. I have tried the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('Button__StyledButton-iESSlv dJJJCD Button-dtUzzq kHUYTy')[0].click;
```

It does not give me an error, it just comes back with the message in the console log:

> ƒ click() { [native code] }

but the button doesn't get clicked

Comment: Click is a function. Use `.click()` if you want to invoke a click? This might be just a typo.

Comment: Now I feel stupid - that worked perfectly

Comment: It's not stupid. Sometimes it is just a matter of needing a second set of eyes, or a rubber duck